# python lists copying is it deep copy or Shallow copy and how is it done?

Tags: python, list, shallow-copy, deep-copy

How is Deep copy being done in python for lists?

I am a little confused for copying of lists.  Is it using shallow copy or deep copy?
Also, what is the syntax for sublists? is it `g=a[:]`?

Answer (score 3):

The new list is a copy of references. `g[0]` and `a[0]` both reference the same object. Thus this is a shallow copy. You can see the `copy` module's `deepcopy` method for recursively copying containers, but this isn't a common operation in my experience.

Stylistically, I prefer the more explicit `g = list(a)` to create a copy of a list, but creating a full slice has the same effect.

Comment: Can you take a look at my answer and confirm whether the statement in the docs is wrong or right?

Comment: @PeterShinners.. That's what I'm confused at. I don't understand why, but `copy.copy` and `copy.deepcopy` is behaving the same way when I try with `a = [1, 2, 3]`

Comment: Your sequence like `[1, 2, 3]` is only a single container. The difference between shallow and deep copies only matters when containers are nested. It may help if you experiment with nested containers like this, `[1, 2, ["a", "b", "c"]]`

Answer (score 0):

From [Python Doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) you have to use `copy.deepcopy(x)`